# How do i exit a block of code after error detection

Tags: c#-4.0, razor

In VB/VB.NET, exiting a block of code anytime and anywhere in the code block is handled using EXIT SUB/EXIT FUNCTION/EXIT LOOP e.t.c. I expected RETURN FALSE should work in razor/c# but its not in a function nor sub-routine.its just @{ }.This gets me confused.please, whats the trick or criteria behind this?
for example

```
@{
if(Websecurity.isAuthenticated){
   //do something
}else{
   json.Write("<li>You must be authenticated</li>", writer);
   return false; //this is my line of question
}
   //remaining code block
}
```

Line 6 is my line of question to exit the remaining code block just like EXIT SUB in VB.NET or VB

Comment: Are you asking about after an exception is throw?  Or do you mean data that is failing a validation test you are performing?  Could you provide code to illustrate you question a little better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try just `return;`, should work.

Comment: @IfeanyiChukwu No Problem :) Fell into the same Problem once. It's just little different syntax  but could cause a headache for sure.

Comment: @Dominic. To vote up the answer, i need 15 reputations.....I'm 4 away from it.tried twice.

Comment: @IfeanyiChukwu reputation limit shouldn't stop you from clicking the check-mark to accept this answer.  It will help Dominik's reputation, and encourage others to help you in the future.